# Como adicionar dois campos de resultados em uma query já formada no SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Preciso adicionar dois campos em uma query já existente no SQL SERVER, porém não sei como adicioná-las em uma query já existente.

Irei tentar detalhar mais o que quero com as imagens abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tenho essa tabela que me dá os valores mensais e sua porcentagem.

Preciso que antes da linha 1, ele me dê um total dos cálculos do ano passado
e entre todos os seguintes valores que já existem nesse calculo, e
também, o cálculo de todo ano vigente na última linha, com todos
esses valores.

Deixarei o código fonte abaixo para que possam averiguar.

```
    DECLARE @anoy int
    SET @anoy = YEAR(GETDATE())
    DECLARE @mesy int 
    SET @mesy = YEAR(GETDATE()) - 1 

    SELECT SUM(total) total
    from (
        select sum(workOrder) as total from workOrder where workType = '02' and year(workOrderDate) = @mesy
    union all
    select sum(workOrder) as total from workOrder where workType= 'corretiva' and year(workOrderDate)= @mesy
    ) s;

    WITH subresults AS 
                ( SELECT MES = MONTH(workOrderDate), 
                preventiva = (SUM(CASE WHEN WorkType = '02' AND workOrderDescription = 'preventiva' THEN 1.0 ELSE 0 END )),
                corretivas = (SUM(CASE WHEN workOrderDescription = 'CORRETIVA' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)), 
                total = SUM(CASE WHEN WorkType = '02' AND workOrderDescription = 'preventiva' THEN 1.0 
                ELSE 0 END + CASE WHEN workOrderDescription = 'CORRETIVA' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) 
                FROM WorkOrder WHERE 
                YEAR(workorderDate) = @mesy
                GROUP BY MONTH(workOrderDate)) 
                SELECT s.MES ,s.preventiva ,s.corretivas ,s.total, 
                preventivasPct = CASE WHEN s.total <> 0 THEN(s.preventiva / s.total) * 100.0 ELSE NULL END,
                corretivasPct = CASE WHEN s.total <> 0 THEN(s.corretivas / s.total) * 100.0 ELSE NULL END 
                FROM subresults s
```